# cannot find RIMIDEWin32Util.dll

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

Am running Eclipse 3.5 and Blackberry eclipse plugin but when I try to create a new Debug configuration, a Java style dialog pops up saying -

cannot find RIMIDEWin32Util.dll

Incidentally, I found that file in this folder in my Blackberry workspace but not sure why it doesn't find it -

C:\Volumes\Data\Code\Blackberry workspace.metadata.plugins\net.rim.eide.bootstrapper\installDlls

Also, when I  run as Blackberry Simulator, the Progress for Packaging New_configuration hangs at 9% and then I have to kill and restart Eclipse.

Anyone experience similar issues?

P.S. : Previously, I had an older version of the BB eclipse plugin and things worked fine but this started happening on the new version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, apparently, the solution to the problem is as described here -

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800901/Support_-_Error_when_debugging_-_Cannot_find_RIMIDEWin32Util.dll.__This_is_a_required_component_of_the_IDE.?nodeid=1450223&vernum=0

That is, I needed to install a 32 bit version of JDK and set the PATH and JAVA_HOME as described here -

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Cannot-find-RIMIDEWin32Util-dll/td-p/143982

Refer also -

[How to set java_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Arunabh Das' solution seems to be the common solution.

However, I've fixed this problem by setting the JAVA_HOME and path variables to point to my x64 Java JDK, and then point my Eclipse to use JDK as the Java reference instead of the JRE.

My system:
Win7 64bit
Eclipse Indigo 20110916-0149 64bit
BB plugin  1.5.0.201112201607

Comment: Could you give some more information? I'm having this problem and your solution isn't working for me. I'd really like to avoid downgrading to 32-bit if I can avoid it

Comment: I can't seem to be able to point Eclipse to JDK for Java reference, since BB project complains that it's not a BB Java environment then... no bonus there :(

Answer (score 0):

No matter if you're on  32/64 bit, if you are using Eclipse, just ensure using a 32bit version, both for Eclipse and JDK 6