# Windows 7 Grails installation

Tags: java, grails

I am working with Groovy & Grails for the first time and having trouble getting the local Windows 7 environment to accept the correct locations of the paths to the bin. Well at least I think after following the www.grails.org\Installation.

Here is what the prompt feedback is showing:

```
C:\Groovy Grails\grails-1.3.7>gradlew

ERROR: JAVA_HOME might be set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk
1.7.0_03\bin;

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation if there are problems.
```

The system cannot find the path specified.

Any suggestions to get going in grails?

Answer (score 5):

take off the /bin, just use: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk 1.7.0_03

never tried to build grails. here what happened:

```
R:\dev\grails-2.0.1>gradlew --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'R:\dev\grails-2.0.1\gradle\assemble.gradle' line: 56

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
Cause: Could not find property 'org' on root project 'grails-2.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating script.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl
.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:51)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.
apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:127)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.appl
yScript(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:82)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.acce
ss$000(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$1.ru
n(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.exec
ute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:114)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.apply(AbstractProject
.java:847)
        at org.gradle.api.Project$apply$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.gro
ovy:31)
        at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at build_7hj6n9uur9rg08bs08d0m02icl.run(R:\dev\grails-2.0.1\build.gradle
:245)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl
.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:49)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.
apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:127)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.evaluate(BuildScriptPro
cessor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectEvaluator.evaluate(DefaultProj
ectEvaluator.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProj
ect.java:487)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProj
ect.java:71)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectE
valuationConfigurer.java:23)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectE
valuationConfigurer.java:21)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer$1.execute(DefaultBuil
dConfigurer.java:38)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer$1.execute(DefaultBuil
dConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractPro
ject.java:463)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.allprojects(AbstractP
roject.java:458)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuil
dConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(Default
GradleLauncher.java:141)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradle
Launcher.java:112)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLaun
cher.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:27)
        at org.gradle.launcher.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReporti
ngAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReporti
ngAction.java:21)
        at org.gradle.launcher.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execut
e(CommandLineActionFactory.java:219)
        at org.gradle.launcher.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execut
e(CommandLineActionFactory.java:203)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.execute(Main.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:
46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:24)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.ja
va:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Wrapper.execute(Wrapper.java:87)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:37)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'org' o
n root project 'grails-2.0.1'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.propertyMissingExceptio
n(AbstractDynamicObject.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDyn
amicObject.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.getProperty(CompositeD
ynamicObject.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated.getProperty(
Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.propertyMissing(BasicScript.gro
ovy:59)
        at assemble_2be0amk65dsfi1le6c3b1ao87h.run(R:\dev\grails-2.0.1\gradle\as
semble.gradle:56)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl
.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:49)
        ... 40 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.287 secs

R:\dev\grails-2.0.1>
```

Comment: maybe add C:\Program Files\Java\jdk 1.7.0_03\bin to the path environment variable. are you trying to run grails or build grails?

Comment: At this point just build but eventually run.  There are scripts from the down load that run to utilize the wrapper. Trying to get that to work.

Comment: got it but your above details didn't make much sense to me.

Comment: that's what happens when i try gradlew with grail 2.0.1. see stacktrace in new edits

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Grails on a Windows 7 machine and had no problems.  My environment variables look like this:

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25

GRAILS_HOME=C:\grails-1.3.8

No problems getting it to run.  But it runs horribly slowly, which it did not do on my xp machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your JAVA_HOME to something like "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7" i.e.to the jre folder instead of JDK folder inside Java directory.(Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7) SO post) This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might be adding quotes to the RC file.

This is the contents of my `%USERPROFILE%\\.groovy\preinit.bat`:

```
set GROOVY_HOME=C:\Path\To\Groovy<br/>
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92
```