# downloading the android sdk - error

Tags: android

to whom it may concern,

I am currently trying to install the android sdk package, however I get to a step and then receive the error: "failed tokh find java version for C:\windows\system32\java.exe: [2] the system cannot find the file specified"

I have successfully downloaded the java jdk on my windows 7 computer, so I am not quite sure why it is saying it cannot find it on my computer?

It also says that "if you believe you have a JDK installed and it was not properly recognised, simply set an environment variable JAVA_HOME to point to it", I have no clue what this means?

could someone please help me with this problem?

Thank you!!

Comment: see [this][1] to set an environment variable JAVA_HOME. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you have installed JDK but enviornment variable is not set.
Follow these steps to set the enviornment variable-

1. Open your jdk folder and locate "javac" file. (Default path is C:\Programs Files\Java\jdk\bin).
2. Copy this path if you were able to locate "javac" and "java" files.
3. Right click on "My Computer" and select properties.
4. Go to "Advanced System Settings". When you click here a new window of "System Properties" will get opened.
5. Click on "Enviornment Variable" button.
6. In new window find "Path" in the second list and double click.
7. In "variable value" you have to add ";.;" without quotes.
8. Click on "ok" button in each window. This will set the enviornment variable.

Comment: thank you for your response, however where do I add ";.;" to?
As in, there is a long variable value, do i add ";.;" to the beginning or to the end??

Comment: You need to add to the end of the value which is already there. put ;.; and then the new path of "javac". Also if it worked for you, pleasse mark it as acceptable answer.

Comment: If you found it useful then make it as acceptable or click on up button.