# ElasticSearch getopt: command not found Error parsing arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

So I downloaded [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) from the website and put it in my application directory and ran the command:

```
$ bin/elasticsearch
```

As the [directions said](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/installation.html) but run into the error:

```
$ bin/elasticsearch
bin/elasticsearch: line 137: getopt: command not found
Error parsing arguments!
```

Its talking about this line in the file:

```
args=`getopt vfhp:D:X: "$@"`
```

What's wrong here? Anyone else have this problem?

I'm running on Windows 7, Ruby on Rails 3.1.0.

**ANSWER**

OK So at first I just clicked on the file:

```
C:\elasticsearch-0.19.8\bin\elasticsearch.bat
```

and it said I needed to **JAVA_HOME environment variable**. You can do learn how to do that here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7
```

Now everything is working after doing the following.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running Windows you should run the `elasticsearch.bat` batch file instead of the shell script `elasticsearch` that you are trying to run.

Answer (score 3):

While javanna's answer is correct, I just want to add that it's possible to run elasticsearch bash script using cygwin as you tried to do. You just need to install package called `util-linux`, which is not installed by default.