# phonegap command execution using php script

Tags: php, cordova, upload

I am using php and want to craete a android application folder using phonegap.

I tried the following command
shell_exec('cd C:\Desktop\phonegap-2.4.0\lib\android\bin  && create C:\phpshell3 com2.wesdr.ddxf dcddf')

but it is giving the following error:

```
Missing one of the following:
JDK
Android SDK
Apache ant
```

But when i execute the same command directly over command prompt it runs fine. How to execute phonegap-android create command using php script on command prompt?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a PHP issue. It looks like you're missing the Android SDK. You'll probably need to download and install it first.

Comment: it  is working fine when i directly use command prompt. i want to execute thsi command using php

Answer (score 0):

you may try coment out the conditional statement in create.bat

```
::FOR %%X in (android.bat) do (
    ::SET FOUND=%%~$PATH:X
    ::IF NOT DEFINED FOUND GOTO MISSING
::)
```

Answer (score 0):

to install jdk u can find it here: https://jdk7.java.net/download.html
after installation jdk u should add JAVA_HOME to enviroments in windows machines.
like here:[How to set java_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7#3024721)

then download android sdk and add its path to enviroments. 
after sdk download ant from http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi and put its bin folder into enviroment like sdk u did.
to test java enter 'java' in cmd and 'ant' for ant and 'android avd' for sdk.
they must have result