# javac not recognized as an internal or external command etc

Tags: java, path, javac

I'm new to coding and javac is not recognized.
I read that I need to change my path, but what I tried didn't work.
My current path is: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin'.
What's wrong?

Comment: The JRE specifically doesn't include the compiler to save space. Use the JDK instead.

Answer (score 5):

`JRE` is different from `JDK`. You need `JDK` in class path to compile program.

Set JAVA_HOME as `C:\Program Files\Java`

Assuming you have `JDK` inside Java folder. You will see `javac` inside `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk...\bin`

Comment: +1, but (and I'm aware the answerer doesn't allude to it), but I have reservations on adding a particular JDK version to your PATH. This is because when you update your JDK, you need to remember to update PATH to point to the new binaries. Recipe for difficult debugging.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I agree with you, but I prefer not having multiple versions, if you are new to Java world.

Comment: thanks for the fast reactions!

Comment: so i should change JAVA_HOME?

Comment: I would start from there.

Comment: where can i change it?

Comment: @user2800605: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7

Comment: okay, step 6 is: Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit

Comment: to be honest, i got to: Set the JAVA_HOME Variable

Once you have the JDK installation path:

Right-click the My Computer icon on
your desktop and select Properties.
Click the Advanced tab. Click the
Environment Variables button. Under System Variables, click New.
Enter the variable name as JAVA_HOME.
Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit.
Click OK.
Click Apply Changes.

Comment: i dont understand whats above btw

Comment: Okay, i managed to set JAVA_home to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40. What's next?

Comment: i did some research and i figured it out myself! If anyone wants to know: my JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40 and my path = %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: @user2800605: Good luck! that is all you need, little bit research instead of worrying too much about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> JRE is different from JDK. You need JDK in class path to compile
>   program.
>
> Set JAVA_HOME as C:\Program Files\Java
>
> Assuming you have JDK inside Java folder. You will see javac inside
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk...\bin

By @Nambari

And next increment on PATH variable the real path of jdk\bin, like:

PATH = *old paths*\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk...\bin.

Hope it helps. ^^ 
(Sorry guys, i use the blackquote to indicate the @Nambari answer couse i'he no suficient reputation do comment)