# Browser prompting for old version of java that does not exist on the machine

Tags: java

Already tried resetting internet explorer settings and clearing browsing history. It continues to look for java 6 u29 when the only version installed is 7 u45. Already tried the old java remove tools.

Comment: What is your JAVA_HOME environment variable value? You can point that to 7u45. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Go to Java under the control panel and check what is the JRE version that it refers.