# How to locate my Maven path in commandprompt?

Tags: java, maven

I have Windows7  and I'm trying to install maven and test it.

But I realised that I have a problem with JAVA and I have to it solve first.

I do Start->Run->cmd

and when I type in the command line,

```
C:\>mvn clean
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment. Please set the JAVA_HOME variable 
in your environment to match the location of your Java installation
```

So i say: Let's set the PATH for Java and i did:

Start->Control Panel->System->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variable->System Variables

Edit the PATH variable

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32;C:\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;
But then i get the same error when i do:

C:>mvn clean

Then i typed in the cmd prompt:

```
  C:\>java -version
  java version "1.7.0_07"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b11)
```

And I realise that the Java version that is running is not located under the `C:\Program Files\Java` directory

The only JDKs I have are: jdk1.6.0_29 jdk1.6.0_32

Then I did Run->cmd

C:>where java
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
(Recently i downloaded IDE Eclipse and IDE IntelliJ and i don't know if these apps come with the JDK).

c:\ >javac

It's working fine

C:>java

this is also working fine

How to resolve above problem any one can help me out?

Comment: Maven looks for `JAVA_HOME` variable. You have to set it to point to JDK.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You need to set `JAVA_HOME` to the location of you JDK install.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7

Comment: open a new command promot it does not auto refresh vars inside an already opened prompt

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly indicated you have not set the JAVA_HOME in system variable yet.

The action you have done was only adding java directory into PATH system variable.

What you should do:

1. Navigate back to Start->Control Panel->System->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variable->System Variables
2. Create new environment variable called "JAVA_HOME" and set value to directory of your java installation. e.g. "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin"

Comment: And then open a new command prompt to get the new environment variable settings

Comment: Thanks for the replay.but I set classpath in Environment Varible.and when I type javac in cmd i got call details for that command