# Maven MojoExecutionException

Tags: java, maven, opendaylight

I am facing this issue , when i am deploying my application using Maven, please suggest some solution.

Error log,

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.790s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Apr 23 10:44:13 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 54M/131M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project clustering.services: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\..\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :clustering.services
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

set `JAVA_HOME` to jdk not to `JDK_DIR/jre`, See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7) question for how to set the value

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Eclipse, go to Windows->Preferences.
Under Java->Installed JREs, double click on the item in the list and make sure the JRE home points to a JDK (for example, set it to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60"), and leave everything else the same.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time that i get this "Mojo" error.  It is just because, i may have forgotten to do **"Maven generate-sources"** then **"Maven Clean"** prior to do the **"Maven Install" or "Maven Build"**.  The MojoExecutionException should not appear after that. Some Eclipse versions have this problem to refresh the target folder. In this case, Refresh the project just after the **"Maven Install"**.

[image]

**If not resolved yet**, it could be a lot of things (failed to copy a file(s), missing file(s), etc).  I would suggest that you run the Maven Install in debug mode by adding -X to get more details on what may have happened then check your log: Right click on project> Run As> Maven Build as the following screenshot:

[image: Compile with -X]

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the name of the main class to execute in the application is specified in the pom.xml.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <mainClass>com.enterprise.mainPacket.MainApp</mainClass>
</properties>
```

Also check if the .fxml file has been relocated, so that it correctly addresses the controller associated with it. fx:controller="com.enterprise.mainPacket.FXMLController"

```
<VBox fx:id="vBMasterContainer" prefHeight="698.0" prefWidth="800.0" styleClass="theme" stylesheets="@/styles/style.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.enterprise.mainPacket.FXMLController">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I fixed the path to Java, and was missing the tools jar. I copied it from another place. After that, everything worked.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you don't have any empty packages within your source code folder. If there aren't any classes, the same error will occur.

Answer (score -1):

Check that there are no conflict on the port (another service already running) !

Answer (score -1):

After I changed the version in `pom.xml` to 1.2.1, the error was resolved.