# How to handle Maven MojoExecutionException?

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, netbeans, single-sign-on

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec
> (default-cli) on project Oauth2SinglesignOn: Command execution
> failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

This is the error I got while creating a java application in NetBeans. There is no syntax errors shown. I got error on execution.

Comment: Can you add `-e -X` to your Maven command? That will show you a lot more information. Sometimes still not enough, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set JAVA_HOME to jdk not to JDK_DIR/jre, See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7) for how to set the value
Refer this [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235430/maven-mojoexecutionexception) also.