# When I start a java program, I can see two jvm instance running in the task manager. My platform is Windows, and IDE is IDEA

Tags: java, jvm

[image]

And when the program exits, there is still a jvm instance, like this:
[image]

What is the function of the second jvm instance?

Comment: IDEA is itself a Java program. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, when I terminate the left jvm instance after program completed, the IDEA won't exit. So the left jvm instance must not be the IDEA process.

Comment: I still think it could be an instance of the JVM that IDEA uses. When you right-click the process and go to 'Properties', it'll tell you the path to the executable - does that path happen to be in your IDEA install directory?

Comment: No, the two instances are all the same path:jdk8/bin

Comment: Then I don't know. If you really want to know, you could use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to find out who started the process and which command-line flags were passed.

Comment: [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is helpful. I find that the left process is started by IDEA, but not itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "jps": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html

```
> jps -l
5334 scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner
5853 sun.tools.jps.Jps
5838 /home/reza/.i/tools/sbt-0.13.9/bin/sbt-launch.jar
```

Maybe these questions help you about that:
[How to execute "jps'' command on Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330488/how-to-execute-jps-command-on-windows-8) and [How to set java_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)