# libGDX project generator: Build Failed : Cannot find java system compiler

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse, libgdx

while generating a project libGDX throws thid error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':core:compileJava'.
> Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a              
JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option                                      
to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

my java  and jdk version :

**java version "1.7.0_65"**

**OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.1) (7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.1)**

**OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)**

What should i do?
plz HELP!!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/6521412/2158970

Comment: TBH I don't even remember why I asked it or what I was doing, sorry @Shiro

Comment: I solved that problem. I think you were most definitely using a JRE folder instead of JDK, in your project, just like me. So you couldn't compile your libGDX project properly