# JAVA_HOME is not recognized as an internal/external command

Tags: java, windows, java-home

I've tried just about everything but it will not recognize it.

I have the latest version of JDK installed, the path is located at "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25". This is what I'm using for my "variable value" field when I add the new variable "JAVA_HOME"..

I also have a `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` in my path variable. I've restarted multiple times, making small changes..

Help me :(

Keep in mind I don't have much of a clue of what I'm doing.. So I could be going about it completely wrong.. Running it in cmd

Comment: show us the actual text of **EXACTLY** what you type in.

Comment: It will be better to show a screenshot of your Environment Variables settings, you can right-click on My Computer and select Properties, select the “Advanced system settings” link, System Properites==>Environment Variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, I was able to get it running using a Shell Script. Turns out, for what I needed this for I did not need to set up a new Environment Variable for it :)

Answer (score 5):

Change the path value %JAVA_HOME%\bin, instead of set this

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin
```

After setting that, open command prompt and check whether you have set JAVA_HOME correctly.

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
java
```

**echo %JAVA_HOME%** will print the location where java installed and **java** will show the usage of java.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17142065/3496666) how to set JAVA_HOME