# IntelliJ IDEA can't run application with JDK

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

When I run my web application with Tomcat, I get an error as follow:

> Caused by: Unable to find a javac compiler;
>
> com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
>
> Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
>
> It is currently set to "D:\jdk1.7.0_60\jre"

I set JAVA_HOME in Configuration, but unfortunately no effect.

[image]

SDKs setting in Project Structure:

[image]

========================================================

Problem has been solved!
Application get exception when doing Ant *javac* task, set the "fork" property `true` then it find `extJavac`.

Appreciate @Michael Hobbs and @Dimitri Hautot.

Answer (score 0):

*JRE* means "Java Runtime Environment". There is no *javac* compiler in it.

The JRE is actually a subfolder of the JDK (*Java Development Kit*, where the compiler is).

Make sure your paths are correctly set in IntelliJ settings, and refer to the JDK, not the JRE.

EDIT: looking at the proposed path, all starting with "D:\jdk1.7.0_60\jre", maybe you installed a JRE on your computer, instead of a JDK. This might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I just set "D:\jdk1.7.0_60" in jdk home path, but I don't why Intellij use "D:\jdk1.7.0_60\jre" when running application.

Comment: The missing class, `com.sun.tools.javac.Main`, is found in my JDK in a *classes.jar* file, which is definitely not in the JRE subfolder of my JDK. Try deleting and declaring again the JDK in Intellij?

Comment: I use System.getProperty("java.home"), its print D:\jdk1.7.0_60\jre

Comment: Do you find anywhere below "D:\jdk1.7.0_60\" the aforementioned file _classes.jar_? If no, I suspect you Windows-wide JAVA_HOME value is indeed pointing to a JRE, not a full JDK. Try fixing this first

Comment: but System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") print the right path D:\jdk1.7.0_60

Comment: I really think you shouldn't rely on a globally set JAVA_HOME variable. You have to fix the SDK definition in your project settings. As previously asked, do you have the _classes.jar_ file somewhere below D:\jdk1.7.0_60\ ? Or can you install a fresh JDK and use it instead?

Answer (score 0):

Project Structure -> SDK does not effect JAVA_HOME. This must be set in the OS. I'm surprised IntelliJ, ran with a JAVA_HOME issues. Should be something alone the lines of:

Linux shell export JAVA_HOME=/home/michael/jdk1.7.0_65

Windows [How to set java_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

Comment: I use System.getProperty("java.home"), its print D:\jdk1.7.0_60\jre

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about windows but on Linux that was a no go for me. IntelliJ failed to start with that as the setting. 
does not work: export JAVA_HOME=/home/michael/jdk1.7.0_65/jre 
works: export JAVA_HOME=/home/michael/jdk1.7.0_65