# Cannot locate java installation error for logstash

Tags: java, path, logstash, java-home

I downloaded Logstash-1.5.0 on Windows 8.1 and tried to run it in the command prompt.

First I checked the java version.
Then changed the directory to `logstash-1.5.0/bin`
then entered the command `logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { elasticsearch { host => localhost } stdout { } }'` it gave the following error:

> Cannot locate java installation, specified by JAVA_HOME

The Logstash folder is on C: and the version of Java is 1.7.0_25. I've set the JAVA_HOME environmental variables to the `jdk` /bin directory, but still it doesn't work.

I'm new to Logstash. Can somebody tell me in detail why this happens and help me fix it?

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` should point to the directory above `bin/`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set java\_home on Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` environmental variables like this:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25 
PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin
```

Comment: You can even declare JAVA_HOME the same way within cygwin. No need to use the /cygdrive path.

Comment: I'm surprised it needs *both* environment variables (both `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`?). But , logstash does say: `Using JAVA_HOME=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe retrieved from PATH` -- so I guess PATH is important! Then why is `JAVA_HOME` also needed?

Comment: @TheRedPea JAVA_HOME may not require in this specific case. But Its good practice setting JAVA_HOME. Cause some java based application (eg. - tomcat, ant) depends on JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you. Another clarification; should we change the `PATH` **User** variable, or the `Path` **System** variable? ([Related stuff here]). And it turns out that if you *don't* set `JAVA_HOME`, it will still complain: `JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set!`. Thanks again!

Comment: For some reason my `AWS` instance would not listen to my environment-variable changes (kept looking in the `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\...`! Even though `PATH` did not mention that), so I just used `set` commands in the command-line session to change them temporarily. Notice also I have newer version, your version may change `set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin` and `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that I set the `JAVA_HOME` variable with a space in the end:

```
"set JAVA_HOME=c:\Programs\Java "
```

instead of

```
"set JAVA_HOME=c:\Programs\Java"
```

And logstash couldn't figure that out :) Removing the space fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows when you change environment over the system settings, you have to close and reopen the command shell, before the changes take effect.

Step by step:

1. Locate your java JRE installation directory you want to use. For example: **"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"**
2. Open start menu right click computer and select settings. In System settings window on right side click on "Extended Systemsettings".
3. On Tab extended select environment variables, add your `JAVA_HOME` variable to your path and hit OK.
4. Open command shell and check environment by entering "set" and hit enter. Look if `JAVA_HOME` is set.

If your `JAVA_HOME` is now correctly set, logstash should work.

Comment: On Windows, just using SET in a batch file will make things more easy wihout needing to alter system config

Comment: Good point about restarting the command prompt! This fixed my issue.