# could not find java - Windows Server

Tags: logstash, java-home

I installed Java SRE and JDK. I rebooted the server. I am still getting the "could not find java; set JAVA_HOME or ensure java is in PATH" error. What else should I look for to solve this? Thanks

Here's my PS output. I shortened the Path to just show anything related to Java.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> cd C:\ElkStack\logstash-5.6.2
PS C:\ElkStack\logstash-5.6.2> .\bin\logstash.bat
could not find java; set JAVA_HOME or ensure java is in PATH

PS C:\ElkStack\logstash-5.6.2> $ENV:Path
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\
Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_361\bin

PS C:\ElkStack\logstash-5.6.2> $ENV:JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_361
```

My C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath shortcut shows java.exe correctly.

I tried changing the JAVA_HOME to c:\progra~1\Common~1\Oracle\Java\javapath and restarting my PS instance with the same results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows JAVA HOME problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229019/windows-java-home-problems)

Comment: This might help: [cannot-locate-java-installation-error-for-logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427355/cannot-locate-java-installation-error-for-logstash)

Comment: @Alejandro I went through that post and nothing helped

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis I checked that one too, if you look at my PS code, and other attempts to fix it below, I tried all the ideas in that post