# install spring boot CLI in windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, spring-boot

I would like to set up a dev environment on my Windows 7 machine so i can create a spring-boot application.  However, i'm having a hard time installing Spring-boot on windows.

This is what i have done so far:
-Downloaded spring-boot CLI zip package and unzipped in C drive 
-JAVA_HOME variable set to c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_14 
-SPRING_HOME variable set to C:\spring-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT 
-Added SPRING_HOME/bin to PATH environment variable

It says to add symlink to auto-completion script but i do not know how to do that.  Not surprisingly when i test installation with "spring --version" command, it fails.

Anybody has done this before?

Thanks!

Comment: If i go to C:\spring-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\bin using command prompt and type "spring --version" this works, but it doesn't when i'm not on this path.  I don't understand since the path was added to the environment variable

Comment: Try to install java in a folder without spaces .. for example in c:\java\jdk1.6.0_14

Also try to use java  1.7 or 1.8

Answer (score 11):

[Instructions for setup](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/v1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-cli/src/main/content/INSTALL.txt) are bit misleading for path setup.

For Windows, Environment variables section, need use `%SPRING_HOME%\bin` [referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024721/452708) in place of `SPRING_HOME/bin` for the system to pick up `SPRING_HOME` environment variable.

Where `SPRING_HOME` is an environment variable for specifying path to the spring boot directory.
E.g. :- `C:\Program Files\Spring\spring-1.2.7.RELEASE`

Note: `bin` folder is not included in the `SPRING_HOME`.

I was able to get it up, here are screen grabs of process.[image]

Alternatively you can have the path setup directly without SPRING_HOME, just append the environment variable `path` with directory path of your "spring.bat" file `C:\Program Files\Spring\spring-1.2.7.RELEASE\bin;`.

Comment: If you need to download Spring-boot CLI, look under [section 10.2.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-installing-spring-boot.html)

Answer (score 0):

Windows looks in the current directory before searching the path. So, when you're in the `bin` directory it sees the `spring` command there and does not look at the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.MANUALLY INSTALLING THE SPRING BOOT CLI
spring-boot-cli-2.0.0.M1-bin.zip is installed.
2.Extract spring-boot-cli-2.0.0.M1-bin.zip.
3.After  spring-2.0.0.M1 extractd.
4. Direct command prompt
--------------------------
C:\Users\nepl>spring --version
'spring' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\nepl>E:

E:\>cd Nagarjuna

E:\Nagarjuna>cd "spring applications"

E:\Nagarjuna\spring applications>cd spring-2.0.0.M1

E:\Nagarjuna\spring applications\spring-2.0.0.M1>cd bin

E:\Nagarjuna\spring applications\spring-2.0.0.M1\bin>spring -- version
'--' is not a valid command. See 'help'.

E:\Nagarjuna\spring applications\spring-2.0.0.M1\bin>spring --version
Spring CLI v2.0.0.M1
E:\Nagarjuna\spring applications\spring-2.0.0.M1\bin>spring --help

E:\Nagarjuna\spring applications\spring-2.0.0.M1\bin>spring run HelloWorld.groov
y
Resolving dependencies......................................................

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::             (v2.0.0.M1)

2017-12-15 15:36:07.949  INFO 3464 --- [       runner-0] o.s.boot.SpringApplicat
ion               : Starting application on nw0188 with PID 3464 (started by nep
l in E:\Nagarjuna\spring applications\spring-2.0.0.M1\bin)
2017-12-15 15:36:07.996  INFO 3464 --- [       runner-0] o.s.boot.SpringApplicat
ion               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: def
ault
2017-12-15 15:36:08.689  INFO 3464 --- [       runner-0] ConfigServletWebServerA
pplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.Anno
tationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@48cd5e87: startup date [Fri Dec 1
5 15:36:08 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-15 15:36:11.575  INFO 3464 --- [       runner-0] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat
.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-12-15 15:36:11.606  INFO 3464 --- [       runner-0] o.apache.catalina.core.
StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-12-15 15:36:11.606  INFO 3464 --- [       runner-0] org.apache.catalina.cor
e.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
2017-12-15 15:36:12.285  INFO 3464 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loa
der.WebappLoader  : Unknown loader org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.Extende
dGroovyClassLoader$DefaultScopeParentClassLoader@526a6c66 class org.springframew
ork.boot.cli.compiler.ExtendedGroovyClassLoader$DefaultScopeParentClassLoader
2017-12-15 15:36:12.378  INFO 3464 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[loc
alhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-12-15 15:36:12.378  INFO 3464 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.Context
Loader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3689
 ms
2017-12-15 15:36:12.550  INFO 3464 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.Servlet
RegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-12-15 15:36:12.550  INFO 3464 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterR
egistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-15 15:36:12.550  INFO 3464 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterR
egistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-15 15:36:12.550  INFO 3464 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterR
egistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-15 15:36:12.550  INFO 3464 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterR
egistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-15 15:36:13.070  INFO 3464 --- [       runner-0] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMapp
ingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.
servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@48cd5e87: sta
rtup date [Fri Dec 15 15:36:08 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-15 15:36:13.200  INFO 3464 --- [       runner-0] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMapp
ingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.util.Map HelloWorld.home()
2017-12-15 15:36:13.209  INFO 3464 --- [       runner-0] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMapp
ingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.Res
ponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframewo
rk.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet
.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-12-15 15:36:13.209  INFO 3464 --- [       runner-0] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMapp
ingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.spr
ingframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web
.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequ
est,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-12-15 15:36:13.242  INFO 3464 --- [       runner-0] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleU
rlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class or
g.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-15 15:36:13.242  INFO 3464 --- [       runner-0] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleU
rlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.spring
framework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-15 15:36:13.289  INFO 3464 --- [       runner-0] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleU
rlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [clas
s org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-15 15:36:13.976  INFO 3464 --- [       runner-0] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBe
anExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-12-15 15:36:14.170  INFO 3464 --- [       runner-0] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat
.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-12-15 15:36:14.175  INFO 3464 --- [       runner-0] o.s.boot.SpringApplicat
ion               : Started application in 8.06 seconds (JVM running for 77.714)

2017-12-15 15:37:42.225  INFO 3464 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[loc
alhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-12-15 15:37:42.226  INFO 3464 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.Dispatc
herServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started

2017-12-15 15:37:42.249  INFO 3464 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.Dispatc
herServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization complet
ed in 23 ms
```