# Problems with System.getProperty("java.home")

Tags: java, windows-7, java-home, system-variable

I run Windows 7 with different JRE/JDKs installed. I try to set the JAVA_HOME path to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45". I tried multiple ways to do that like described in [How to set java_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7).

I think it worked, because in the advanced System Properties, the new path is shown and the command echo %JAVA_HOME% also returns the new path. But when I invoke the following program via cmd

```
public class JavaVersionShower {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, System.getProperty("java.home"));
    }
}
```

the message window says "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66".
I also cannot use the JavaCompiler API which is only available if the used java version is a jdk.

Comment: Do you have different Java installations on your system?

Comment: did you restart CMD after you changed java home?

Comment: I have different java installations on my system (like I already said in my question) and I did restart the cmd after I changed JAVA_HOME; my java installations are: jdk1.7.0_51, jdk1.8.0_45, jre1.8.0_45, jre1.8.0_60, jre1.8.0_66

Comment: which jre did you run that with? I think "java.home" refers to the installation directory of the jre currently running. Have you tried asking for the system property "JAVA_HOME" from inside Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating java home and path is little different in windows 7 and 8. You might need to go to "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" to update them. This article might be helpful to you [Update Java path in Windows 8](http://howtolearnjava.com/change-java-home-and-java-path-in-windows-7-or-windows-8/)

Ravi