# Can't find JDK to set JAVA_HOME variable to

Tags: java

I've installed java SE and downloaded and installed the JDK here the below link but can't seem to find the JDK file to point JAVA_HOME to. Please help I just want an environment to learn java in!

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: Get Eclipse or IntelliJ idea these will automatically provide you the intial environment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set java\_home on Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [netbeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) that will provide you an excellent IDE to begin with **Java**. Its easy to use and awesome IDE.

Download netbeans with Java SE version which you will find on their download page.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is some sort of linux.  This how to do it in ubuntu.
http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Your-Java_Home-Path-in-Ubuntu

I don't believe windows needs a setup other than running the installer.  Also look into eclipse as it is my favorite IDE for Java and super easy to use.  Sounds like you're new to Java.

Comment: Apologies I should have noted it is indeed windows. I downloaded netbeans as recommended by Pankaj and it seems to work fine. Thank you for your answer anyway