# Lucee Express on local Dev

Tags: cfml, lucee

I’m currently running window 7, ACF 11, and IIS 7 and would like to install Lucee express to try.

I’m having the hardest time getting Lucee to work on my local desktop. I followed this article http://www.gpickin.com/index.cfm/blog/setting-up-lucee-in-my-dev-environment-changing-ports I can’t get the Lucee welcome page to work.

- I download the Lucee Express from here http://lucee.org/downloads.html
- I extract the file to C:\lucee
- Ran the  C:\lucee\bin\startup.bat
- Navigated to 127.0.0.1:8888
- I get the follow message: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8888

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance for your insights.

Comment: And startup.bat didn't report anything amiss, and there's nothing relevant in any of the log files?

Comment: thanks for your response! I get a spit second flash of the dos prompt window and that's about it. I don't see anything logs (C:\lucee\logs)

Comment: ah. Don't doubleclick on startup.bat... start your CLI *then* run it. When Lucee face-plants the window will stay open, and you'll be able to see your problem. Suspect it's that you don't have JAVA_HOME set..?

Comment: You nailed it "Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program"! Now I need to google how to do this... thank you very much for your insights!

Comment: @user752746 - You can set it as an [environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7) OR edit `startup.bat` with notepad, and hard code the path via a set statement. I already had ACF installed, and did not want to install another jre, so I hard coded the path just after the "setlocal" statement at the top: `set "JRE_HOME=C:\Dev\ColdFusion\jre"`

Comment: Hi Leigh, thanks for your insights.

Comment: Just an FYI for others wanting to try Lucee locally. You can install CommandBox https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/commandbox and fire up a local dev instance of Lucee via CLI very easily. OS X users can 'brew install commandbox'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As identified in the comments on the question: you are missing the environment variable pointing to your Java runtime (you need one of `JAVA_HOME` or `JRE_HOME`.

This can be achieved in one of a coupla ways.

Set it globally:

Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables > System Variables > New...

Or set it for just that environment by editing the startup.bat file you've already been using:

```
SET JAVA_HOME=[path]
```

In both situations you need a path to either a JRE or a JDK. You say you have CF11 already installed, so you can simply point to its one, which will be a subdirectory of your CF install, as Leigh points out above. So something like:

```
SET JRE_HOME=D:\apps\Adobe\ColdFusion\11\express\jre
```

If you have a Java JDK installed instead and want to use that, use `JAVA_HOME` instead of `JRE_HOME`, eg:

```
SET JAVA_HOME=D:\apps\Oracle\Java\jdk\1.8.0_60
```

As these things can be installed anywhere, you'll just need to locate 'em and use the path accordingly. You want to point it to the top level directory of your JRE or JDK, which contains the `bin` subdirectory.

Comment: Hi Admin, thanks for detailed response. This is very helpful, I'm sure others will fine this helpful as well. Cheers!