# Visual Studio - Minecraft Mod Dev - Change JDK Location?

Tags: java, visual-studio-2015

Problem I have a newer JDK installed and I need to change the path to that JDK instead of version 73, however I can't find anywhere on the IDE to do this.

```
Error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73 MinecraftMod2   EXEC    0
```

Comment: ```JAVA_HOME``` is also an environment variable, which it might be referring to.

Comment: What is visual studio doing here? :)

Comment: @mjn +1 hehe eclipse is so much better at java

Comment: Mostly just curiosity i prefer IntelliJ usually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JAVA_HOME environment variable which points to the SDK can be set either for the current user only or for everyone, in the Windows computer settings 'Environment variables' dialog.

See for example

[How to set java_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

Comment: Completely forgot about this , Thanks!

Comment: @TzZek mark this as your answer if it answers your question