# phonegap build is run but java -version error

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

My system is in install some application like:

Phonegap v6.2.5

node v5.6.0

java jdk1.8.0_60

java jre1.8.0_91

I am build android app using phonegap, but some error, like:

**[phonegap]** executing 'cordova build'...

Error: Failed to run "java -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: bin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBjHd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, so that Cordova can find the Java JDK. You can find detailed instructions [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7).

Comment: Run `echo %JAVA_HOME%` in your command line to see its contents. It's probably mistyped, because the error message says that it's "invalid".

Comment: I am run `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and output is `%JAVA_HOME%`.  I thing run `echo $JAVA_HOME` and output is **blank**, but JAVA_HOME environment is set.