# APTANA error for first RUN in Windows 7 (the last verison)

Tags: python, windows

I am a rookie in programming, but I need to program in Python language because I need it in  my field. I googled some applications for programming in W7, but there was just few programs for writing codes in graphical windows. I tried to install 2 programs: JetBrains Pycharm & AptanaStudio, but non of them worked on my laptop! I used google for my issues, but I didn't find any useful links and the program just logged the error and there was no link for guidance!

***The Aptana error is:***

---

### Aptana Studio 3

```
Java was started but returned exit code=13
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-Xverify:none
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\Users\failedtoopen\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86
-showsplash
-launcher C:\Users\failedtoopen\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\AptanaStudio3.exe
-name Aptana Studio 3
--launcher.library C:\Users\failedtoopen\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup C:\Users\failedtoopen\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 239c_80
-vm C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-Xverify:none
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\Users\failedtoopen\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
```

---

### OK

[the error when running AptanaStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzqO0.jpg)

How do I fix this and how do I use other program called PyCharm, when I have JDK error?

Before any help:
I installed last version of JDK from Java and restarted my pc, but nothing happened!

***PyCharm Error is:***

---

### Error launching PYCHARM

```
Failed to create JVM: error code -1.
JVM Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre
If you already have a 64-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in 
Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables.
```

---

### OK

[the error when running PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csep2.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set java\_home on Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

Comment: Thanks for Downvotes

Comment: Yea k thank yo.....5....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just reinstall Java on your machine. First remove Java completely. You might even use this tool from Sun:

- https://java.com/en/download/faq/uninstaller_toolinfo.xml

There is also this handy utility for removing / repairing Java:

- https://singularlabs.com/software/javara/

Then just download and install the latest Java for Windows.

Alternatively, you could use a Python IDE that does not depend on Java at all. There are many that don't. For example:

- Wing IDE
- Komodo
- Pyzo

There are a bunch of others listed here:

- https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments