# The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\\bin\javac.exe" is invalid

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Ok im wondering where does xamarin get this path from?

Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
Error       The specified task executable location `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\\bin\javac.exe"` is invalid.

So I can go and change it to the new jdk1.8. I have the new JDK set up I just need to know where to change the path at.

Comment: Have a look at your environment variables. For example, look at the PATH and JAVA_HOME. (Or reinstall Xamarin and let it pick it up, maybe...)

Comment: I have repaired Xamarin and reinstalled Java.  the PATH enviroment variable goes to C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath, I do not have a JAVA_HOME (or anything else using Java)

Comment: Please have a look for java home setup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7

Comment: I did still didnt work. the JAVA_HOME I created was C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and solution is.

1. Remove all jdk and install jdk 1.8
2. Change reference java location in Visual Studio Tool > Options > Xamarin
3. Clean and Rebuild Project

Comment: Thanks so much. "Clean" was the Magic keyword.

Comment: Is rebuild supposed to do a clean first? Seems to "sort of clean" but not quite. Anyway - this...

Comment: Cleaning the solution was key for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved this exact problem for me.
I don't know why you wouldn't have a JDK_HOME variable. Completely remove the JDK and install it again maybe?
The `Environment Variables` for java were set to my previously installed path. I guess Oracle screwed up here.

As I had the same error, here's what I did:

I went to `C:\Program Files\Java\` and checked what the jdk folder is called. For me it's `jdk1.8.0_102`.

For users who don't know where to find `System Variables`:
Go to `System Properties` and on the left hand side, click `Advanced System Settings`. Switch to the `Advanced` tab, click `Environment Variables`. Under `System Variables` there should be two variables in the list called `JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME`.

I edited those values and change the path to what I found in the java folder. In my case this would be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102`.

No need to close VS, just build your app and it should get passed the annoying error.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I got it to go away (which is not the same thing as fixing it).

- Un-install every bit of JAVA you have. Delete both JAVA folders (Program Files and Program Files (x86)).
- Install the latest version of the Java (x32) SDK.
- Clean and Rebuild your project(s).
- Since my Solution is multi-platform, I changed the Startup Project to the .iOS one, built it, ran it in an emulator, and set the Startup Project back to the .Droid project.

Somewhere in all this, the problem went away.
And remember kids! If it can *go away* all by itself, it can *come back again* all by itself!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, I downloaded 32 bit Java but VS was still looking for the 64 bit one.

To solve it all I had to do was change the JAVA_HOME and the variable in my Path, clean my project and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

Just set JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME ambient variables, clean your solution and build again. For me worked fine.
Don't forget to clean your solution.