# JAVA_HOME is invalid for Ionic run android

Tags: ionic-framework, java-home

[image: Error for the Java_HOME image]

This is the image for the error i have encounted, as you can see, I have already targetted the JAVA_HOME into the jdk, as for my PATH, i have already targetted to the bin of the jdk which is.. D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin

Is there anyone able to help resolve this issue? As I was doing this fine yesterday, and today when I started off my computer, it didn't work as how it works yesterday. I'm a beginner to ionic and system/user environment variables user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set java\_home on Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

Comment: when you run "java -version" in a cmd, do you get a result back or an error? if no result, I'm agree with Leonardo, you should check your configuration for the java path. Check both JAVA_HOME and Path to your java bin in your windows variables as described there http://stackoverflow.com/a/17142065/5404186

Comment: It is able to show something,

java version "1.8.0_101"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

. And what I have done is exactly like the link you have given to me.