# keyclock server is not working on windows?

Tags: java, jboss, keycloak

**I am trying to install key-clock server but when I run standalone.bat file exception being thrown.**

I am using JDK 7.

[**Image with exception**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUt3p.png)

Comment: It doesn't sound like your `JAVA_HOME` is defined correctly.

Comment: which path i have to menthin in JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6521412/365237

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If is the latest version try running with JDK 8 instead 7.