# Talend opening error

Tags: talend

I like to open talend from my computer and it does not work but it works in an other computer.
I don't inderstend the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you must add your jdk path to system PATH variable.

[How to set java_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

otherwise you can run TOS using command line with -vm argument :

TOS_DI-win-x86_64.exe -vm "< JRE_PATH >\jre\bin"