# Could not find any executable java binary

Tags: java, node.js, express, elasticsearch, mean-stack

please help with my problem that I'm facing since hours. I'm trying to run ElasticSearch-5.2.2 with MEAN Stack. I installed Java JDK 8 and I set the path correctly and also added this path *"\Oracle\Java\javapath"* still I'm getting the same error `"Could not find any executable java binary. Please install java in your PATH or set JAVA_HOME"`. Why it is happening can anyone help me out?

Comment: you say " I set the path correctly" - can you tell us what you did to set it correctly so we can make sure you actually did do it correctly?

Comment: I went to environment variables and added variable name: JAVA_HOME variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin and in System Variables in Path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said you "*went to environment variables and added variable name: JAVA_HOME variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin*"

This is incorrect. **Don't** include the bin directory when you set JAVA_HOME.
Set `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121`

Once you are done with this, test it.
Open command prompt and type `echo %java_home%` and see if its printing the path you set.

Comment: Wow, Perfect Man! You are right. Appreciate your response.

Comment: That's why I asked :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows?

If so open your system environment variables and add a new one named JAVA_HOME and point it to your Java JDK

You can double check how to do this by referring to the thread here [How to set java_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

But what have you tried so far?