# The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly, but it is defined correctly! Ubuntu 18.04.01

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to run maven on Ubuntu. Every time I run something like `mvn -v` I get: 
"The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE".

The thing is that I have set JAVA_HOME correctly.
In /etc/environment: `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"`.

Also, if I try `echo $JAVA_HOME`it returns "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle", which is correct.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: As indicated by error, your current `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to `JRE` instead of `JDK`. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496192/java-home-should-point-to-a-jdk-not-a-jre/43496275

Comment: execute `env` command in terminal to check `JAVA_HOME` property set or not

Answer (score 0):

Most probably ubuntu source /etc/environment is set by default. If it does not work you need to add the below line inside ~/.bashrc

open it using nano/vim or any editor with sudo perimissions. Then add below line

```
source /etc/environment
```

Comment: I have already run 'source /etc/environment' and JAVA_HOME is up to date.

Comment: @NikosLeventis not only run. you need to add it to  .bashrc using text editor

Comment: I added the line in ~/.bashrc but I still get the same error