# JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE + JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, ubuntu

I've edited my `.bashrc` file on my server, with **`sudo nano ~/.bashrc`**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
```

I've re-logged in, and here is all the path as output:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01:~/maifee/backend-spring# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/bin/java
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01:~/maifee/backend-spring# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/bin/java/bin
```

But when I try to run my spring boot server, it gives me:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01:~/maifee/backend-spring# ./mvnw spring-boot:run
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/bin/java/bin/java
```

And when I try to do a `mvn install`, I get:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01:~/maifee/backend-spring# mvn install
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

But here is the java configuration list:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01:~/maifee/backend-spring# sudo update-alternatives --list java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

And when I try to run(just tried, without installing dependencies), I get:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01:~/maifee/backend-spring# ./mvnw spring-boot:run
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/bin/java/bin/java
```

How can I set up my environment to correctly, run my Spring Boot server? I directly have source code there, I don't even need compiling and stuffs.

Comment: You need to point JAVA_HOME to your JRE in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java or /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java. 
Seem like in usr/bin/java/bin/java don't have Java executable file.

Comment: For example, set `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` and then `PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAVA\_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496192/java-home-should-point-to-a-jdk-not-a-jre)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JAVA_HOME` sould point to the base installation dir of java:
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/` not `/usr/bin/java` which probably is a symbolic link to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`

then in `PATH` variable you append `$JAVA_HOME/bin`

So it should look something like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

FYI update-alternatives is only responsible for changing the symlink of java to point it to different versions of the executable,
think of it as a simple `ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java /usr/bin/java`