# Java_home path cannot be set

Tags: maven, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, java-home

I am using linux subsystem with Debian 10. I installed Java 17 and set the Java homepath to jdk 17.
The JAVA_HOME Path ist still java-11, but this isnt even installed.

[image]

```
echo %JAVA_HOME% set set JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle echo %JAVA_HOME%
%JAVA_HOME% set set JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

I tried to change the home variable permanently, but it does not work.

Well? Still exception
[image]

Downloaded java versions
[image]

installed java version
[image]

How can i change the Java_Home path permanently.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Add all information as text not as link

Comment: You have installed a JRE but You need a JDK

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAVA\_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496192/java-home-should-point-to-a-jdk-not-a-jre)

Comment: There is a jdk-17. U see it in "downloaded java version" annd why is it stll java 11?

Comment: You use the windoes commands on linux that wil not work. use `export JAVA_HOME=...`

Comment: Thanks, i did it but: ❯ export JAVA_HOME=\usr\lib\jvm\jdk-17

~
❯ mvn -version
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

Comment: What do you get if you use `echo $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: No output, strange ...

Comment: echo $JAVA_HOME
usrlibjvmjdk-17

Comment: In linux you have to use `/` not  backslash

Comment: okey, thank you ❯ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17

Comment: than it should work

Answer (score 0):

If you install JAVA through your distro's default package manager(for example I use Ubuntu so I install Java(the OpenJDK version of Java) through APT [so the command to install OpenJDK's Java17 for example is `sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk`]). Regardless of the version you install via APT, Java will be installed in the `/usr/lib/jvm/{java-version-distribution-architecture}` path. So, the easiest way to set the JAVA_HOME variable is to edit your `.bashrc` file and add this inside it using your text editor:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Save and close the file after adding this information inside it. Then run the command `source .bashrc`(to stamp you changes) and the JAVA_HOME will be permanently set. Also note that the `.bashrc` file is located in the `~/.bashrc`(your home). You can confirm the JAVA_HOME variable by using the command `echo $JAVA_HOME` on the terminal and it should show you the path you just set. I hope this helps

Comment: The enhancment of PATH is not necessary...

Comment: Thank you ! I am using zsh and in the zshrc there was export -> java11