# Running maven through command prompt

Tags: java, maven

I am running my maven build through my command prompt where I set the M2_HOME variable in my system variables. However, when I run a `mvn compile` in my command prompt I get the following error:

`no compiler is provided in this environment. perhaps you are running on a jre rather than a jdk`

but when I run the goal `mvn compile` in my eclipse GUI it works fine.

---

When I added this to my `pom.xml` it was able to compile in my command prompt but I need it to work without have to place that in my pom.

```
<plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.1</version>
     <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <executable>C:\programfi\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\javac.exe</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

This is NOT a duplicate question since other questions similar to this is asking for the eclipse GUI, where I am asking for command prompt.

Comment: What do you get when you type the command `javac` in the command prompt? Make sure that the JDK `bin` directory is in your `PATH`.

Comment: @Jesper when I run java -version in my command prompt, it spits out the version so I am assuming it is set correctly.

Comment: But what about `javac` (the Java compiler), not `java`?

Comment: oh, when i use javac it complains. K going to try to set that as my path variable and see if that works

Comment: Ya, try setting JAVA_HOME and PATH variables correctly. See third answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7

Comment: Cool. btw, did setting JAVA_HOME and PATH solve the problem?

Comment: @entpnerd Unfortunately, I won't be able to know until tmw because I need admin credentials to change system variables on my machine. And all the admins left for the day. I will answer back once I have checked and I will accept your answer if you want to add it below.

Comment: @robben I'm pretty sure that you can try this before tomorrow. Try temporarily setting the environment variables in your command shell like this answer suggests. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29413794/4851565

Answer (score 1):

set your jdk path and also set maven path into `.bash_aliases` file(hidden file) in home directory :-

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/hadoop/install/jdk1.8.0_92
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH


export MAVEN_HOME=/home/hadoop/install/apache-maven-3.3.9
export M2_HOME=/home/hadoop/install/apache-maven-3.3.9
```

Additional details for *nix systems and Windows systems [has been published by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/)

Comment: This will most likely not help, because robben seems to be using Windows and these instructions are for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You should add Java to your environment variables. Try hitting Windows, search for environment variables and again click the button

> Environment Variables...

Then change or create the Variable named: JAVA_HOME, pointing to your Java installation, as you mentioned: C:\programfi\Java\jdk1.8.0_73

Make sure you MAVEN_HOME is correct too.

Then click OK, close the command prompt that is opened and open a new one.
Try execution mvn -v and check it the Java version is the one you indicated. If it is, it probably will work on CLI and not just on Eclipse.

It's also worth mentioning that Eclipse not always points to the same JDK and Maven from your system. You should make sure that your command line interface and your Eclipse are using the same tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try [setting up your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2619584/4851565) to point to the JDK you referenced in your question. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6521412/4851565) is a good answer on how to do this. Note that the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable shouldn't contain the `\bin` directory, itself. Additionally, to get `javac` to run correctly on the command line, you need to add `JAVA_HOME\bin` to your `PATH` environment variable as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024721/4851565).