# Jenkins and maven JAVA_HOME not found in your environment

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job, that should be run by slave, that is on Windows Server 2012 (amd64).

It connects with the repository successfully, but when I want to add an **Invoke top-level Maven targets** step, I get this ERROR

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment. Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation
```

Okey, that looks like I need to find a jdk directory and show a pass to it. But I don't really know, how to do it. I tried different command define a correct location of JAVA_HOME

**which java**

```
/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath/java
```

**whereis java**

```
java: /cygdrive/c/IBM/RationalSDLC/common/java /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath/java.exe
```

So what is a path to JAVA_HOME in my case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to system , environment variables, user defined variables, then set the JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 2):

Please look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

You have to set JAVA_HOME that points to your JDK installation path.