# Trouble installling elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having trouble installing elasticsearch on windows 7 professional. When I click on elasticsearch.bat it  gives me the following error:

> 'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. Could not find any executable java
>   binary. Please install java in your PATH or set JAVA_HOME Press any
>   key to continue . . .

Comment: Have you tried setting Java_home like the error states? [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6521412/833070)

Answer (score 0):

This means you haven't installed java or you have not set JAVA_HOME path properly. First Install java and then try installing elasticsearch