# ""Java"" is not recognized as an internal or external command, program or batch file. in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm starting with kotlin on windows, I'm following the steps of
[Working with the Command Line Compiler](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html)

And I get the following error after trying to compile(and add the bin directory in the path of my system):

**Comand compile**:

```
$ kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar
```

**Error**:

```
""Java"" is not recognized as an internal or external command, program or batch file
```

in my windows CMD.

I need to have java installed on my pc. To start with kotlin?

Comment: Yes, you need to install the JDK to use Kotlin.

Comment: Install java and set you environment variables - If you are using Windows 10 link is [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/)....For windows 7 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Java 8 JDK (not JRE) on your development machine as it is a prerequisite for running the Kotlin compiler, and also for any Java or Kotlin application.  You can use either the [Oracle JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) for most platforms or [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/install/) for Linux platforms.