# Issue JDK creating a scala project in Intellij

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I have installed the JDK jdk-8u144-windows-x64.exe in my computer in order to set up the tool IntelliJ to play with Scala, well before move forward to IntelliJ installation I ensured the JDK in my computer:

running path:
[image]

the running a java version:

[image]

Then, I installed the IntelliJ and the Scala plugins, so when finally I'M going to create my first project my laptop configuration is not mapping the JDK:

[image]

I tried to add the required environment just clicking on new and go thru the path where I installed the jdk but it doesn't go thru either.

[image]

Please, guys, I'm a bit nooby with Scala and IntelliJ, could you please guide me a bit. I tried to follow the instructions in this link but it is not going thru. https://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started-intellij-track/getting-started-with-scala-in-intellij.html

thanks

Comment: Press "New" and point to home directory of JDK.

Comment: take at look what I got clicking on new @Dmytro Mitin

Comment: Try not `bin` directory but `jdk1.8.0_144`.

Comment: It worked thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have set environment variable JAVA_HOME  to your java directory, IntelliJ detects JDK using that environment variable, or you can browse the path of java installation directory using "New" button beside jdk and select it.

Comment: In my experience, IntelliJ sometimes ignores `JAVA_HOME` and forces you to use the New button to manually set it up.

Comment: So, if I will include the java_home in systems variables, I should add a new variable called JAVA_HOME pointing on the jdk folder?

Comment: @AndresAngel Yes.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7

Comment: @AndresAngel
`PATH` should point to `bin` directory but `JAVA_HOME` to `jdk1.8.0_144`.