# run-nifi.bat : The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly

Tags: java, apache, apache-nifi

I have developed a JAVA application for signature verification and I want to develop an Apache Nifi Processor for this JAVA application.

When I want to run .bat file in cmd i.e. run-nifi.bat I get this error :

> "The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly. Instead
>   the PATH will be used to find the java executable."

Also I can not find my processor at `http://localhost:8080/nifi`

Answer (score 1):

Just define JAVA_HOME system environment variable and point it to your JDK dir. More detailed answer: [How to set java_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)