# Problem with netbeans 9.0 on Manjaro Linux

Tags: java, netbeans, archlinux, manjaro, netbeans-9

I've been using Netbeans 8.2 on Manjaro Linux for a while with no problem at all. Today I made an update of my system and I found that it installed the new Netbeans 9.0 but since that I can't use my old 8.2 version. I tried to uninstall and re-install it with no results. So I decided to try to use the new version but everytime I try to open it by my desktop or menu icon nothing happen. So I tried to open it by command line and I get this message:

```
Cannot read cluster file: //etc/netbeans.clusters
```

I'm just using Netbeans for my thesis work so I'm not an expert at all, so I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem with freshly updated netbeans.
I noticed that I had *netbeans.clusters* file in */usr/etc/netbeans.clusters*
Just copied them to etc and netbeans started...

```
cp /usr/etc/netbeans.clusters /etc/netbeans.clusters
```

...but it recommended me to install *nb-javac* library and also it had some negative effect on my home directory (got all config files in there), so this might be only temporary solution.

Answer (score 2):

This same issue was recently opened on the Arch Linux bugtracker, so I know why you have this problem: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/60533

The doubled `//` is sort of suspicious, and furthermore, the file as installed by the package is in fact `/usr/etc/netbeans.clusters` -- which is identical except for the missing "usr" component. It turns out that this is set by the netbeans [startup shell script](https://github.com/apache/incubator-netbeans/blob/9c74075e7982c99028ea68f4427ebc19781ea476/nb/ide.launcher/unix/netbeans#L38-L55) by parsing the location of the shell script (using the dirname for `$0`) and considering that to be the root of your netbeans install. This needs to be equal to `/usr` in order to work properly. For reasons obvious to anyone who really groks shell, this shell script is terrible (as are most on the internet), but the important factor for you to consider is that it depends on how you ran it.

For some reason, you're running the program via `/bin/netbeans` instead of `/usr/bin/netbeans`. Probably because `/bin` is in your system `$PATH`, which is wrong and is a bug in your system.

The result is that the terrible netbeans shell script miscalculates the netbeans basedir as `/` instead of `/usr`, and miscalculates all resource files relative to the wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be problem of update center you need to register NetBeans 8.2 update registry:
[Ref 1](https://sunilkanzar.wordpress.com/2018/08/02/plugin-set-up-in-netbeans-9-0/), [Ref 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578345/apache-netbeans-9-0-java-error), [Ref 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=am-7aa2hYgc)