# Can't run sdkmanager.bat, error message JAVA_HOME is not set

Tags: android, batch-file, cmd, java-home

I am trying to install android sdk through command line tools, in most of the tutorials it says that I should run android.bat from tools folder but cmd opens and then closes after a second or two, so I tried with the `sdkmanager.bat from tools\bin\sdkmanager`.bat but the same happens.
I googled and found some information so I tried running it from cmd, android.bat is deprecated it says, but when running sdkmanager.bat or avdmanager.bat it gives me an error: `JAVA_HOME` is not set

**Here is the screenshot:**
[image: error message from cmd]

I tried following the steps as in: [How to set java_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

But after I did it and tried running it again in cmd, my problem is now this:
[image: Second error after setting up JAVA_HOME]

Comment: Seems quite obvious, You haven't set the JDK path in your environmental variables.

Comment: lookup on the internet how to set the JAVA_HOME variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set java\_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

**To Set JAVA_HOME in Windows:**

1. Right click My Computer and select Properties.
2. On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then edit JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located, for
   example, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\
3. If you don't have JDK software.
   Go to [http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp.](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp)
   Select the appropriate JDK software and click Download.

Comment: There was no JAVA_HOME variable so I created one with the directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, probably not, but anyways, this is what pops up now after entering the same command

https://imgur.com/t1ztPaz