# System cannot find the path --- Apache Kafka Zookeeper

Tags: cmd, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

When i want to start a Zookeeper-Server with the command line I get the message that the system cannot find the path. Yesterday everything was fine and the code/path was correct. Today the system cannot find the path.

This is the content of my `cmd.exe` window which was opened 'As administrator' on Windows 7:

```
C:\Users\KESSP2>cd Documents

C:\Users\KESSP2\Documents>cd kafka

C:\Users\KESSP2\Documents\kafka>.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.

C:\Users\KESSP2\Documents\kafka>
```

Comment: Does `zookeeper-server-start.bat` have `@echo off` at the beginning?  If so, comment that out or delete it and run again. It is probably complaining about a different executable that it cannot find.

Comment: I wont suggest windows to run kafka, however when I do I use GitBash and the `.sh` version instead of the `.bat` since I got issues with it as well

Comment: I delete the @echo off at the beginning. Now the cmd show the text from the bat-Datei before complaining about the path.

Comment: @Paizo can you give me the command for GitBash? I haven't worked much with GitBash

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do the files still exist under `bin\windows\`? Is this definitely the right directory that you were using yesterday? Have you tried removing the leading `.\`?

Comment: Definitely the right directory. I already used TAB for auto-fill and the system still cannot find the path

Answer (score 0):

See if you have JAVA_HOME defined and pointing to the right folder (your java folder might change after jdk version upgrade) in windows system variables (see [How to set java_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)).