# Got error when i try to run Zookeeper server

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to run kafka server in my local computer .

(i do it step by step like in this tutorial : 
http://javainuse.com/misc/apache-kafka-hello-world).

When i tryin to make this command :

```
.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
```

i get this error message :

> **The system cannot find the path specified.**

[click here to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OS1e.png)

Comment: Sounds like you're in the wrong folder when you try running that

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51654919/system-cannot-find-the-path-apache-kafka-zookeeper/51655319#51655319).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not in the correct directory. 
To get your working directory, fire up a Command Line and run

```
cd
```

Make sure that your working directory is the kafka folder; for example:

```
C:\Users\giorgos\kafka_2.12-0.10.2.1
```

and then run the command:

```
.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
```

Comment: Show us the content of bin

Comment: when i m google it there is people that say maybe i need to change something in the variable environment (the solution for windows 7 i m with windows 10)