# JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.(Spring Tool Suite)

Tags: java, spring-boot

`JAVA_HOME` does not point to the JDK.(Spring Tool Suite)

I am getting  an error while running Spring Tool Suite(3.9.5.RELEASE) as

```
org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181"
```

As i already set the java path in Environmental Variable-->System variables as
Variable Name : `JAVA_HOME` and 
Variable Value : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

and in Environmental Variable-->user variables as

Variable Name : `path` and 
Variable Value : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

and in my C:\Program Files\Java\ drive there is jdk1.8.0_131 and jre1.8.0_181.

I set the `path` properly to JDK, also I restarted the application too, even restarted the Computer too, still I am getting the same error again.

Is there any other solution to avoid such error?

Comment: is javac working on cmd?

Comment: Yes, its working fine

Comment: hey buddy JAVA_HOME should point to jdk  not jre example of my path in linux  /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_171

Comment: check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7 .try echo %JAVA_HOME% in cmd see if the correct path is set

Comment: i did all the settings properly, as provided link by you..Now the  the error coming  as:            
                                     
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre"

as i set the path to jdk and jre creaed inside JDK , hence i unable to run the Spring boot app, frustated a lot with this error..

Answer (score 1):

Check your project build path if it is pointing to JRE instead of JDK.

**Else Check**,

1. The path for the tools.jar, if it is wrong? or,
2. Is it pointing to an older version of Java? or,
3. If tools.jar is missing?

If all the above options do not work try reinstalling JDK.

Comment: i did all the settings properly, but it still shows the error as:                                                 
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre"

Comment: Set `JAVA_HOME="C:\\....\java\jdk1.x.y_zz"` and set `PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Comment: did,  but still shows as JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK. and when i checked in cmd prompt it shows the correct path of JDK .It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre", as it pointed to JDK but, inside JDK it point to JRE folder where its create a problemi wanna get rid of this .. tough for me

Comment: @ArvikShukla remove the jre at the end C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre it should be C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131

Comment: @Manoj Ramanan i set the path as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131 by gooing to Windows-->Preference-->Add-->and the i set the JRE home as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131, but when i try to check build path by right click on project-->BuildPath-->Configured Build Path--> i see that it configured to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre, but i set the path path till JDK,its beyond understand why its point to jre even after setting the path till jdk..

Comment: First of all delete all the path you set for JAVA in environment variable And then as I mentioned Set `JAVA_HOME="C:\\....\java\jdk1.x.y_zz"` and set `PATH=C:\\...\java\jdk1.x.y_zz"\bin`. Follow these steps for above mentioned `https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml`.

Comment: Follow these steps for eclipse setting https://techiedan.com/2009/10/19/set-up-jdk-in-eclipse/

Comment: @Pallav Kabra, The link you provided to set up the JDK  in eclipse, i did this exactly as shown there in the link , and if you notice, look at the 3rd  image (EDIT JRE window)where the path is pointing to JRE as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre, there i gettinga  problkem that as error show to me is 

Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre"

Comment: and also i added dependency from my side as 

 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
     <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
     <version>1.8.2</version>
  </dependency> 

as previously tomcat was not running so i added ant dependency so its started to detect embeded tomcat but niow after solving that problem now it shows this Point to JRE errors.. i think its due to dependency of ant it shows me a problem ??

Answer (score 0):

I installed STS in eclipse Python instead of using separate STS tool and problem got solved..Still wonder why the path shows in STS tool point to jre even after setting to JdK...but i install and  run STS in eclipse and it worked properly, wasted my 2 days on this error. 
Thanks for your time , learned a lot about settings from you guys