# ERROR: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: /Users/samir/Library/Android/sdk/bin/java

Tags: java, android

I recently open the parse android project for multiple user login and then IntelliJ IDEA Show much more error and then I follow the steps and I download
 all the requirements but still getting error

> ERROR: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the
>   java executable. Tried location:
>   /Users/samir/Library/Android/sdk/bin/java

[Image of error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XI2s.png)

The java File is

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Parse, LLC.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */
package com.parse.starter;
import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;


public class StarterApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("")
            .clientKey("")
            .server("")
            .build()
    );

    ParseObject object = new ParseObject("ExampleObject");
    object.put("myNumber", "123");
    object.put("myString", "rob");

    object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback () {
      @Override
      public void done(ParseException ex) {
        if (ex == null) {
          Log.i("Parse Result", "Successful!");
        } else {
          Log.i("Parse Result", "Failed" + ex.toString());
        }
      }
    });


    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();

    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

  }
}
```

and it shows error where their is  name **parse**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7 Does this link answer your question?

Comment: No .  This is Not