# Installed Java on Windows 10, Environment Variable Path Setup, throwing error

Tags: java, javac

I have installed Java on a Windows 10 system.

`java --version` works fine as it can show the Java version.

However, when running anything Java-related, the following error is thrown:

> error : could not find java in JAVA_HOME or bundle at C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin/bin/java

I am not sure what is wrong with the configurations.

Below are the attached screenshots:

[image: error Sreenshot]
[image: envioremnt variables screenshot]

[image: tried with java_home and without /bin]

Comment: It seems you only added java installation to PATH variable, but somehow Elasticsearch requires JAVA_HOME to be set.
So you need to have JAVA_HOME pointed to *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1* and PATH variable should contain *%JAVA_HOME%\bin*

Comment: [Perfectly detailed answer is already given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17142065/12718463) Follow this steps carefully

Comment: Thanks for assisting, actually JAVA_HOME and PATH both are done now, on user and system level both. but throwing the same error, also tried path excluding bin, but the error persists. if you look closely its actually missing up the file structure of java, I mean at the end of the error line. \jdk-14.0.1\bin/bin/java.
also please have a look at the third screenshot I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the Bin. Then it should work!

Comment: please check the third screenshot as well I have edited the question

Comment: And did you check in your file explorer that there is a Bin-folder with a java.exe in your  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\?

Comment: ‪C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\java.exe
here it is, yes its present

Comment: And if you cmd: "echo %java_home%", what happens?

Comment: it prints out path correctly.
‪C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1